Finding nearest value in numpy array given another array of values
Suppose you have two arrays of different lengths, such that:
a = np.linspace(1, 10, 25)
b = np.linspace(2, 10, 12)

I am interested in finding in the array a the indexes of the values that have the smallest difference from all the values of the array b.
An easy way to do this (it works) is doing the following:
def find_nearest(a, b):
    indexes = []
    for i in range (len(b)):
        idx = (np.abs(a - b[i])).argmin()
        indexes.append(idx)
    return indexes

However, if a and b are quite long arrays this is not super efficient. Do you think there would be a better way to write this? I'm interested in the case that the array a is longer than array b.

Since your input values are sorted, the most efficient would be to use searchsorted:
a = np.linspace(1, 10, 25)
b = np.linspace(2, 10, 12)

# find closest value such as a[i-1] < v <= a[i]
idx = np.searchsorted(a, b, side='left')

# check if the previous value is closer
out = np.where(np.abs(b-a[idx]) < np.abs(b-a[idx-1]), idx, idx-1)

Output:
array([ 3,  5,  7,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24])

timings
Compared to broadcasting (a has 2*N items, b has N items).


I think you're right, in a sorted case this is the fastest way. I'm trying to figure out the time complexity, is it O(M⋅logN) cause of the binary search?

@Spix737 I think so. An interesting related read.

Interesting indeed and nice graph.

A possible solution, where b[:, None] reshapes b into a column vector, allowing broadcasting to occur when subtracting a, which creates a 2D array of differences.
np.abs(b[:, None] - a).argmin(axis=1)

Output:
array([ 3,  5,  7,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24])


Note that the solution is O(N*M), so this is the vectorial equivalent of OP's approach

Thanks for commenting, @mozway! I believe that, even so, my solution is fast! ;-)

Yes, for small enough arrays, for large ones it will crash by filling the memory ;)

True, @mozway! That is an intrisic problem with broadcasting. However, broadcasting has not been removed from numpy, which makes believing it is generally considered useful!

Of course it's useful. I'm only mentioning this since OP indicated that a/b are large. In their case this is only slow since the search is iterative but won't crash due to memory. However, with broadcasting this is building the full intermediate in memory, which can be an issue.

Got now your point, @mozway! I hope the OP's arrays are not that too long!
